# using Bindinglist as bind for Textbox

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, textbox, bindinglist

I have a bindinglist. i am using a textbox to show its items

```
WithEvents xBind As New BindingList(Of Emp)
```

I added items this way

```
xBind.Add(New emp("alpha0", "B"))
xBind.Add(New emp("alpha1", "B"))
xBind.Add(New emp("alpha2", "B"))
xBind.Add(New emp("alpha3", "B"))
```

I am binding the first property to a textbox

```
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("text", xBind, "eName")
```

It shows "alpha0" in the form which is first item in the xbind
Now how do I display the second item in textbox1 when i click "MoveNext" button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a listbox or grid instead of a textbox, which only shows one value at a time.

Comment: yeah, thats true but i have tons of properties that needs to be shown in textboxes. and traverse using next button

Answer (score 2):

I happened upon this while seeking a solution to a similar question. For anyone else who may come across this, my solution was to use a BindingSource.

```
Dim bsXBind As New BindingSource
...
bsXBind.DataSource = xBind
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsXBind, "eName")
```

To move to another record, change BindingSource.Position:

```
Private Sub NextXRecord()
    If bsXBind.Position < bsXBind.Count - 1 Then
        bsXBind.Position += 1
    End If
End Sub
```